# Know if django-google-analytics-app was installed

Tags: python, django, google-analytics, pip, google-analytics-api

I am trying to install the Google Analytics apps in Django and when trying:

```
django-google-analytics-app --version

django-google-analytics-app -V

which django-google-analytics-app
```

I either get

**zsh: command not found: django-google-analytics-app**

or

**django-google-analytics-app not found**

How could I check if this app has been installed and how could I check its version?

Comment: Have you tried `pip freeze` from within command prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`django-google-analytics-app` will not give you a binary file to get the version against. You can run the following command to see if the package is installed.

```
pip freeze | grep "django-google-analytics-app"
```

If this command gives you some output similar to

```
django-google-analytics-app==<version>
```

then the package is installed. If there is no output then the package is not installed

Comment: Thanks! Yes this gave me a version of django-google-analytics-app. Can I normally put it in the requirements.txt? i.e. django-google-analytics-app==4.4.0 or should I do it differently?

Comment: You can just put it in `requirements.txt`